# SQL select Query performance is very slow with joins

Tags: sql, oracle

Please correct the below query to increase performance back-end. I am using Oracle database

Query execution is very slow:

```
SELECT 
    A.USER_PROFILE_ID,
    B.LAST_NAME||','||B.FIRST_NAME||' - '||B.USER_PROFILE_ID AS EXPR1, 
    A.DEPARTMENT_CODE_ID, 
    C.NAME AS EXPR2,  
    A.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
    A.EFFECTIVE_STATUS, 
    A.INSRT_USER, 
    A.INSRT_TS, 
    A.MOD_USER, 
    A.MOD_TS 
FROM 
    'USER_PROFILE_DEPARTMENT' A,
    'USER_PROFILE' B, 'DEPARTMENT_CODE' C 
WHERE 
    A.USER_PROFILE_ID = B.USER_PROFILE_ID
    AND A.DEPARTMENT_CODE_ID = C.DEPARTMENT_CODE_ID  
ORDER BY 
    EXPR1
```

I couldn't find any please help

Comment: Hello.  Your tagging of the question is all wrong.  If you already know the problem is in the SQL side of things, C# and asp.net have nothing to do with this.  Re-tag your question to whatever SQL engine you are using.  Good luck!

Comment: The "A,B WHERE" join syntax has been obsolete for **30 years** now.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the `WHERE` clause to join tables. Instead, use the `JOIN`
keyword to explicitly specify the relationship between the tables being joined.

For example, instead of writing:

```
SELECT *
FROM "USER_PROFILE_DEPARTMENT" A, "USER_PROFILE" B, "DEPARTMENT_CODE" C
WHERE A.USER_PROFILE_ID = B.USER_PROFILE_ID AND A.DEPARTMENT_CODE_ID = C.DEPARTMENT_CODE_ID
```

You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM "USER_PROFILE_DEPARTMENT" A
INNER JOIN "USER_PROFILE" B ON A.USER_PROFILE_ID = B.USER_PROFILE_ID
INNER JOIN "DEPARTMENT_CODE" C ON A.DEPARTMENT_CODE_ID = C.DEPARTMENT_CODE_ID
```

Some tips when it comes to performance in `SQL`:

- Use appropriate indexes on the columns used in the JOIN and WHERE
  clauses to improve the performance of the query. This can speed up
  the process of finding matching rows in the tables being joined.
- Consider using sub-queries or derived tables to retrieve the data you need, rather than joining multiple large tables. This can improve performance by reducing the amount of data that needs to be scanned and processed.
- Use the `LIMIT` keyword to limit the number of rows returned by the query, if you only need a small subset of the data. This can reduce the amount of data that needs to be processed and returned, which can improve performance.

If the query is running slowly despite these changes, consider using `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to understand where the bottlenecks are and how to optimize the query further.